# SELECT ALL COLUMNS TO COMPARE THE DAY TODAY IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have this table named Schedule and column names with Sunday, Monday, Tuesday and so on.
[Click here to see the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Mej.png)

Is this possible?

`$day = date('l');`

`SELECT * FROM Schedule WHERE COLUMN = '$day'`

So I can show the data under that day-named column.

Comment: `select monday from schedule`?

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Comment: Please add your table definition,sample data and expected reult.

Comment: Please don't add your table definition. Please fix your schema instead.

Comment: Yeah I already tried this one,
`SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Schedule'`, but I think I can't compare it to my table.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly not a big deal using a case statement, for example

```
drop table if exists t;
CREATE TABLE t 
(id int,monday int,tuesday int,wednesday int,thursday int,friday int,saturday int,sunday int)
;
insert into t values
(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
(2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
set @weekday = 'friday';
select t.id,    
         case when @weekday = 'monday' then monday
            when @weekday = 'tuesday' then tuesday
            when @weekday = 'wednesday' then wednesday
            when @weekday = 'thursday' then thursday
            when @weekday = 'friday' then friday
            when @weekday = 'saturday' then saturday
            when @weekday = 'sunday' then sunday
            end as weekdayvalue
from t;
    
+------+--------------+
| id   | weekdayvalue |
+------+--------------+
|    1 |            5 |
|    2 |            5 |
+------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: I got your point so I did this, `if(date('l') == "Sunday") { SELECT Sunday FROM Schedule } elseif(date('l') == "Monday") { SELECT Monday FROM Schedule }` and so on. Thank you so much. Those guys downvoting your answer won't understand 'cause we're not in the same situation. Even argued about the title CAPS, for real, I mean it's a title. Again, thank you, appreciated.